# Integrate web with desktop application

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, xul, desktop

I have to integrate a single page javascript web application which I wrote with a bunch of desktop applications which I don't control, but I'm expected to provide integration instructions.

The initiator of communication is a desktop application. Let say, users presses F5 and browser opens with certain url. A simple way must be provided for the user to return to
the desktop application.

The solution does not have to be browser and OS agnostic. It is OK if it works only for firefox or IE on windows (XP and later).

I intended to create XUL plugin which opens a socket server and launches web application with the received url. For the way back, I would provide a simple button to close the browser window.

Is there a better way to do the integration?

Comment: instead of opening a browser i'm sure the desktop application can have a an embed webview or browser inside itself. would be easier if we knew how the desktop applications were developped

Answer (score 0):

If I got a good understanding of your question, you were asking if there are "other way/better way" of integrating desktop thingy and web thingy?

Desktop and Web are totally two different domains, the best way you do an integration is using interfaces, tho, there are libraries scattered on the net that allows you to utilize each on either web or desktop application.

There is also a vague area about the question detail, you said "I wrote with a bunch of desktop applications which I don't control" does that mean there are multiple systems not specific to one language? eg. apps in C#, C++, PHP etc...

Comment: Yes, the desktop applications are all windows-only but might be written in different languages, even worse, some of them will probably use some outdated technology/language like Delphi. This is why I thought going with socket communication is the best way.